# How copy color width height getpixel and setpixel C#

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

```
![Text](C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AVB1\ass.png)
```

I am trying to do the same thing as in the linked question, but with C#. I am showing a scaled image and am allowing a user to select an area to crop. However, I can't just take the x1y1, x2y2 coordinates from the scaled image selection and crop that from the original. I've tried doing some basic math like in the other question, but that's obviously not the right approach either (it's definitely closer).

```
colors = new Color[zEndPixcel_Y, zEndPixcel_X];//matrix 
    for (int y = zBeginPixel_Y; y < zEndPixcel_Y; y++)
    {
    for (int x = zBeginPixel_X; x < zEndPixcel_X; x++)
                {
    colors[x, y]= zImgProcess.GetPixel(x, y);// get color
    for (int b = zBeginPixel_Y1; b < zEndPixcel_Y1; b++)
    {
    for (int a = zBeginPixel_X1; a < zEndPixcel_X1; a++)
    {
    Color c = colors[x, y];
    zImgProcess.SetPixel(a, b,c); /set color
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using winforms or wpf it wouldnt be any problem as there are so many friendly mouse events and Bitmap builtin functions to do this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.